# How to use curl in my paypal ipn?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm using PayPal in my Donation site and I need to store it in database. I'm using PayPal IPN to do this. Before, it worked on free webhosting i'm using which is 000webhost. But a month later, it didn't work. It has an error of

```
unable to connect to ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443
```

I didn't change any code. But some suggestion are the SSL is not supported by 000webhost free webhosting. My IPN looks like this.

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    $mail = mail('myemail', 'Error at 21', "{$errnum}: {$errstr}");
} else {
    //insert database here.
}
```

My question is, I read 000webhost and it supported the curl in their free webhosting. How can I change my ssl to curl?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should support "SHA-256" and should use "G5".

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en

If you want to try in curl you can use the [code sample](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php)

If you want to ignore SSL(which is no recommended, just for testing) , you can try to disable in line 58,59

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Comment: This is the message in my ipn.log
[2016-02-04 01:23 America/New_York] Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: ya, you will need to upgrade your server

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/), if it helps:

```
$fp = fsockopen('tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

If you decide to try the curl code suggested by Vimalnath, I had to add the line below to make it work in the sandbox: ([ref](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/479))

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I just upgraded my domain. I also used trigger in phpmyadmin, free domain doesn't support it so, I decided to upgrade. :)